# LibGDX not disposing properly?

Tags: java, libgdx, dispose

When disposing of a LibGDX game on desktop, I am noticing some problems. When the window is closed, the application is moved to a background process and not deleted. When even 4 or 5 are not taken care of in task manager, it is enough to bring the system to a crawl. In the console, closing through the exit button or Gdx.app.exit(); produces the following stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.dispose(Game.java:31)
at com.name.game.Core.dispose(Core.java:23)
at com.name.game.Screens.GameScreen.dispose(GameScreen.java:49)
at com.name.game.Screens.GameScreen.hide(GameScreen.java:36)
```

All dispose() methods should be called appropriately, and the dispose() methods dispose of all applicable resources in the class.

Comment: First thought to mind, you may have a circular reference to dispose.

Comment: I think you had the right idea, I found a circular reference between the game world and the renderer. I took them out and it solved both problems.

Comment: @oracleCreeper Please add your answer as an "answer" and "accept" it.  This may be handy for other users in the future. Thanks!  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: @oracleCreeper, I second what P.T. said